# Insert to a specific table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Main PHP file-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyJS.js"></script>
<body>
<?php
    include ("connection.php");

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM stu_rec");

    while($stu = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<h3>" . $stu["Name"] . "<h3>";
        echo "<h3>" . $stu["FirstName"] . "<h3>";
        echo "<h3>" . $stu["SID"] . "<h3>";
        echo "<h3>" . $stu["Email"] . "<h3>";
    }
?>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="Name">
First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName">
SID: <input type="int" name="SID">
Email: <input type="text" name="Email">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<select>
    <option id="mon" value="1"></option>
    <option id="tue" value="2"></option>
    <option id="thu" value="3"></option>
    <option id="fri" value="4"></option>
</select>
<script>
remaining();
</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

File that inserts information to database...

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");

$sql="INSERT INTO table1 (Name, FirstName, SID, Email)
VALUES
('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[FirstName]','$_POST[SID]','$_POST[Email]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";
header('Location: MyPHP.php');

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

the javascript file-

```
function remaining(){
  var mon=8;
  var tue=5;
  var thu=8;
  var fri=9;
document.getElementById("mon").innerHTML = 'Monday 15:00 to 17:00 ---- ' + mon + ' seats remaining';
document.getElementById("tue").innerHTML = 'Tuesday 14:00 to 16:00 ---- ' + tue + ' seats remaining';
document.getElementById("thu").innerHTML = 'Thursday 11:00 to 13:00 ---- ' + thu + ' seats remaining';
document.getElementById("fri").innerHTML = 'Friday 10:00 to 12:00 ---- ' + fri + ' seats remaining';
}
```

I have 4 database tables. Upon selecting monday from the from the drop-down menu, it will insert to "table1", Upon selecting tuesday from the from the drop-down menu, it will insert to "table2" and so on. Please give me an idea on how to do it... I'm very new in this. please adore my silly mistakes!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a name to the select:

```
<select name="my_select_name">
```

and then change the first line of the insert query accordingly:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table".$_POST['my_select_name']." (Name, FirstName, SID, Email)
```

However note you don't do any filtering of the data you retrieve from the user before you insert it to your database, this is really dangerous and open to errors / SQL injections

Comment: It worked! thanks! i'm going to work with validation after my basic work is done! thanks for your suggestion though... you'er great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the menu inside the form, so that its value will be submitted:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="Name">
First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName">
SID: <input type="int" name="SID">
Email: <input type="text" name="Email">
<select name="day">
    <option id="mon" value="1"></option>
    <option id="tue" value="2"></option>
    <option id="thu" value="3"></option>
    <option id="fri" value="4"></option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in your PHP, you can do:

```
$table = "table" . $_POST['day'];
$sql="INSERT INTO $table (Name, FirstName, SID, Email)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[FirstName]','$_POST[SID]','$_POST[Email]')";
```